# How do I access and update nested Mongoose documents

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a mongoose document that is a User. Each user has arrays or words e.g. nouns. I want to be able to update the fields of the words e.g. add a +1 to the frequency or change the status number. I can access the whole array but not the individual items in the array. Also i want to be able to display the items in the array based on their fields e.g. only display those with frequency of 3 or more etc...

I have tried lots of different things but I'm just not getting it. I keep getting back error messages that findOneAndUpdate is not a function, or 'undefined' when I try to access and update documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d8490c1842471c6bcea42"),
    "username" : "eric@mail.com",
    "nouns" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d849cc1842471c6bcea43"),
            "word" : "die Sonne",
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:28.436Z"),
            "frequency" : 0,
            "status" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84a8c1842471c6bcea45"),
            "word" : "das Wetter",
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:40.940Z"),
            "frequency" : 0,
            "status" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84afc1842471c6bcea47"),
            "word" : "der Apfel",
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:47.403Z"),
            "frequency" : 0,
            "status" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84b9c1842471c6bcea49"),
            "word" : "das Maedchen",
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:04:57.388Z"),
            "frequency" : 0,
            "status" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f7d84c8c1842471c6bcea4b"),
            "word" : "das Auto",
            "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-07T09:05:12.036Z"),
            "frequency" : 0,
            "status" : 0
        }
    ],
    "verbs" : [],
    "adjectives" : [],
    "others" : [],
    "salt" : "*****",
    "hash" : "*****",
    "__v" : 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out after hours

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').objectID


db.collections.users.updateOne(
  {},
  {$set: {"nouns.$[element].status": 3}},
  {multi: true,
  arrayFilters: [{"element._id": 
ObjectId(req.body.inputId)}]}
);
```